# records that belong to multiple categories

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a list of persons and the languages they speak:

```
name; language
John; english,italian
Jane; french, spanish, english
...
```

I want to list them (table) and have a barChart of the languages... and I'm stuck

To be able to draw the language, I would pre-process the data to change the format to

```
name; language
John; english
John; italian
Jane; french
Jane; spanish
Jane; english
```

and use the language as the dimension for the barChart... however, I then have duplicates in the table, where I should have John and Janes only once.

How can I handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather short answer, but use the new array dimension feature in version 1.4: https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays That allows you to count each record in more than one group without having to reprocess your data and do any weird aggregation to deal with the duplicates.

(This is in the community fork at https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/ )

Comment: oooh, chrismas is early this year! thanks Ethan, I'm going to upgrade and play a bit with it.

Comment: trivial modification on the data, d.language = d.language.split (",") and voila, worked great!

Comment: Yup. You can do that transformation in your dimension accessor if you want, and not touch the original data.